# Query builder get array of results instead of objects in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

Here's my query

```
DB::table('genres')
        ->join('albumGenres', 'genres.id', '=', 'albumGenres.genre_id')
        ->join('albums', 'albumGenres.album_id', '=', 'albums.id' )
        ->select('genres.id')
        ->where('albumGenres.album_id','=',$this->id)->get();
```

But I get something like this

```
"genre_id": [
        {
            "id": "4"
        },
        {
            "id": "8"
        }
    ]
```

What should I do to get the results as just an array

```
"genre_id" : [4,8]
```

Comment: `$result = array_column($result->toArray(), 'id');` perhaps?

Comment: json_decode($result,TRUE);

Answer (score 7):

With new versions of Laravel, you should use pluck() instead of lists().

```
DB::table('genres')
->join('albumGenres', 'genres.id', '=', 'albumGenres.genre_id')
->join('albums', 'albumGenres.album_id', '=', 'albums.id' )
->where('albumGenres.album_id', '=', $this->id)
->pluck('genres.id');
```

Here is the reference in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#retrieving-results (see 'Retrieving A List Of Column Values')

Comment: Using pluck is not good when you are dealing with bulk data. It is pretty slow.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `->lists('id')` instead of `->get()`:

```
DB::table('genres')
    ->join('albumGenres', 'genres.id', '=', 'albumGenres.genre_id')
    ->join('albums', 'albumGenres.album_id', '=', 'albums.id' )
    ->where('albumGenres.album_id', '=', $this->id)
    ->lists('genres.id');
```

Read more: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects (Retrieving A List Of Column Values section)

Comment: This returns null.
However, using it to query other field works as expected. What?
    `return DB::table('genres')
            ->join('albumGenres', 'genres.id', '=', 'albumGenres.genre_id')
            ->join('albums', 'albumGenres.album_id', '=', 'albums.id' )
            ->select('genres.name')
            ->where('albumGenres.album_id','=',$this->id)->lists('name');`

Comment: @Vector I just edited my answer, try again with updated code.

Comment: @Vector replace `->lists('genres.id');` with `->toSql();` and paste result here.

Comment: select 'genres'.'id' from 'genres' inner join 'albumGenres' on 'genres'.'id' = 'albumGenres'.'genre_id' inner join 'albums' on 'albumGenres'.'album_id' = 'albums'.'id' where 'albumGenres'.'album_id' = ?

(Replaced back ticks with quotes)

Comment: @Vector please run this query in mysql/pgsql console (don't forget to replace `?` with id you want) and paste result here.

Comment: id: 4,
id: 8

It works... 
meanwhile I've just used array_map() to work around this

Comment: Are you sure there is no `->select()` method in your query , when you are trying `->lists()` method?